# ThreadPoolExecutor with ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

Can I pass a non-blocking queue named `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` to `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `LinkedBlockingQueue`(or any other blocking queue)?

Comment: I think technically yes, but based on requirement whether you use blocking or non-blocking queue will be determined.

Comment: Two counter-questions for you: Why do you want to do this? What happens when you try it?

Comment: Constructor specifically states that the queue should be a `BlockingQueue`, the reasons can be found in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` code itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) states that a blocking queue needs to be used.

Please refer to the queuing section.

Answer (score 0):

As antonis said, you must use a blocking queue.  The reason for this is that when the queue becomes empty, the pool must block and wait for more tasks.  Rather than re-implementing this blocking logic in the pool executor itself, the developers leveraged `BlockingQueue`.

However, since `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` implements `Collection`, you can do this:

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Thing> nonBlocking = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
// Do work, enqueue things
LinkedBlockingQueue<Thing> blocking = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(nonBlocking);
```